# Adding new Column to the Existing Table on ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to add a new column to myTable under some conditions but I couldn't manage to do it so far.  (I'm using JS views)

I have a variable called `data`.

Here is mycode

Table ;

```
var vergleichTable1 = new sap.m.Table(this.createId("vergleichTable1"), {
        columns: [
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: data[0].KURZNAME
                })
            }),
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: data[1].KURZNAME
                })
            }),
        ]
    }).addStyleClass("vergleichTable1");
```

And If my `data.length === 3` I want to add another column to my table

What I tried and did not work is ;

```
       if(data.length === 3){
            this.byId("vergleichTable1").addColumn({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                        text: data[2].KURZNAME
                })
            });
        }
```

could someone maybe help & show me the mistake I am doing ? This `.addColumn()` is not really working here

I am doing these both in my `View` but using `.addColumn()` in the `Controller` did not help either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use like below in controller.

```
this.getView().byId("vergleichTable1").addColumn( new sap.m.Column({
                                  header: new sap.m.Label({
                                      text:"hi" //data[0].KURZNAME
                                  })
                              }));
```

What you are doing wrong is you are not passing `sap.m.Column` object inside addColumn method.